# Long task entity framework and web api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, extjs, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I'm building a time and attendance module, using web api and EF 6, that will load an external time sheet file and then will process many rules to validate real working hours by employee.

As my client side Im using **EXTJS**. (Will show a loading icon on Time Sheet Import grid, so user can do other things on the app while the task is running).

Because I don't really know how many time this task will take (probably between 2 to 5 minutes ) I was considering triggering a windows service to execute this "maybe long process task". So, when the user upload the time sheet file I will update a bool flag in a table that will say the **task is in process**. After, the windows service will read that and will start executing all the jobs. At task completion the windows service will update the flag to **task completed**.

1. First question: is the above approach correct?

Now, I have my concerns about how to do the business rules on my task job (windows service), what I need to do is to load all time sheet file records on a temp table and then will have to get all my employees and loop one by one. On each loop I have to see if the time sheet records have any time stamp that belongs to that employee and then go to a many many number of rules like:

- check if employee shift match the entrance and exit time from time sheet record, if not then apply working hours penalty
- check if employee is under vacation so if records are found in the time sheet don't consider them
- check how many late arrival the employee has in a period of time and it the new time sheet record has a new late arrival then apply half day or full day penalty
- in case of late arrival or absent, check if the employee has a day permit authorized. If so, don't apply any penalty.
- and many others rules....

There will be like 1500 employees.

1. Second question: Is it fine to do the loop using EF or is there a better way to do that "one by one employee check and apply rules"?

Comment: If it's a long running task you will need to off load it to a service.  Default IIS will only wait 90 seconds then timeout.  The response you get from the controller will be a timeout.  We use WCF with MSMQ to create the service, works pretty well.  If you want to be updated right away when it's done you can check into a framework like SignalR.

Comment: Can I use signalR to update my client extjs so the user know what is the status or the step of the actual running task? Yes I will use MSMQ to call a console app that will do the long running task.

Comment: I've never worked with extjs.  Calling into SignalR from javascript is pretty simple with lots of information out on the web.

Comment: I will look at it. Thanks a lot. Do you think doing that loop one by one employee approach using EF sounds reasonable?

Comment: I would implement IValidatableObject interface on the entities and EF will auto call that on SaveChanges.  But if one entity fails none of the entities get posted. Usually you won't put all the logic into the validate method that method will call into other objects to do the business logic.